# Back button doesn't work after location.reload in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, back

In my application, I have a button that creates an HTTP promise, and on a successful callback refreshes the page (using `window.location.reload(true)`).  However, this adds a new copy of the page to the browser history, so the back button doesn't work since it's just loading the same page again.  Any idea how I can fix this?

I'm trying to support ie8 if possible.

Comment: Why are you reloading?

Comment: Because the button is clearing out data on the server side and then I was reloading to basically clear out all of the data on the client side.  Lazy, but effective (until now)

Comment: Maybe you should change that. That way the back button works ;)

Comment: Haha yeah, I just did.  I can basically just call my init() function again which will do the gets with empty data.

Thanks for pointing out my stupidity! :D

Comment: However, I'm curious if it's possible to fix it this way, even though I now don't need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments on your question point out that your approach is not optimal. Instead of completely reloading *everything*, you should have a function that updates the (already loaded) view.

However, if you really *insist* on using this behaviour, you could use `location.replace()` instead, passing it the current URL. This will essentially reload the page without adding a duplicate in the history stack.

Answer (score 0):

See this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

> There is a special replace method which can be used to tell the $location service that the next time the $location service is synced with the browser, the last history record should be replaced instead of creating a new one. This is useful when you want to implement redirection, which would otherwise break the back button (navigating back would retrigger the redirection). To change the current URL without creating a new browser history record you can call:

```
$location.path('/someNewPath');
$location.replace();
// or you can chain these as: $location.path('/someNewPath').replace();
```

Note: If you are using AngularJS, I would suggest that you stick to using the $services provided to you by the framework because they will act the same as their JavaScript counterparts except they will also be wrapped with a $scope.$apply to prevent any inconsistencies within your Angular app.